# Door Kerf Weather Stripping - Kerf slot facing the wrong way

Tags: doors, weatherstripping

I have an old 1970's wood door that I am trying to add add weather stripping to. The problem I am having is that the kerf slot in the frame is facing the wrong way. From what I have been seeing, the slot should be facing out the front of the door. The kerf slot on my door faces out the side towards the wall.

It seems like all kerf products are designed for kerf slots that face out toward the door vs out the side of the frame.

Is this called something else? Or is there a different type of product I should use? Because the kerf stuff wont work right with a sideways slot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "kerf mount bulb" or "kerf mount bubble" weatherstripping, rather than the V type you illustrate.

[image: Weatherstripping Image from swisco.com, no endorsement implied]

"P-Profile" might be another or better search term based on the layout (with the strip offset to one side, rather than centered on the hollow part.)

Comment: Thank you. I ordered some of the bulb style. That looks like it should work. Thanks.